# How to submit PySpark and Python jobs to Livy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

Ii am trying to submit a PySpark job to Livy using the /batches endpoint, but I haven't found any good documentation.  Life has been easy because we are submitting Scala-compiled JAR files to Livy, and specifying the job with className.

For the JAR file, we use:

```
data={
    'file': 's3://foo-bucket/bar.jar',
    'className': 'com.foo.bar',
    'jars': [
        's3://foo-bucket/common.jar',
    ],
    'args': [
        bucket_name,
        'https://foo.bar.com',
        "oof",
        spark_master
    ],
    'name': 'foo-oof bar',
    'driverMemory': '2g',
    'executorMemory': '2g',
    'driverCores': 1,
    'executorCores': 3,
    'conf': {
        'spark.driver.memoryOverhead': '600',
        'spark.executor.memoryOverhead': '600',
        'spark.submit.deployMode': 'cluster'
}
```

I am unsure how to submit a PySpark job in a similar manner, where the package also has some relative imports...any thoughts?

For reference, the folder structure is below:

- bar2

  - __init__.py
  - foo2.py
  - bar3

    - __init__.py
    - foo3.py

I would want to then run:

```
from foo2 import ClassFoo
class_foo = ClassFoo(arg1, arg2)
class_foo.auto_run()
```

Comment: Nobody answered? I am also trying to find out how to submit pyspark job with python dependencies via Livy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing pyFiles

```
data={
'file': 's3://foo-bucket/bar.jar',
'className': 'com.foo.bar',
'jars': [
    's3://foo-bucket/common.jar',
],
"pyFiles": ["s3://<busket>/<folder>/foo2.py", "s3://<busket>/<folder>/foo3.py”]
'args': [
    bucket_name,
    'https://foo.bar.com',
    "oof",
    spark_master
],
'name': 'foo-oof bar',
'driverMemory': '2g',
'executorMemory': '2g',
'driverCores': 1,
'executorCores': 3,
'conf': {
    'spark.driver.memoryOverhead': '600',
    'spark.executor.memoryOverhead': '600',
    'spark.submit.deployMode': 'cluster'
```

}

In the above example

```
"pyFiles": ["s3://<busket>/<folder>/foo2.py", "s3://<busket>/<folder>/foo3.py”]
```

I have tried saving the files on the master node via bootstraping , but noticed that Livy would send the request randomly to the slave nodes where the files might not be present.

Also you may pass the files as a .zip,Although I havent tried it

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit with `file` being the main Python executable, and `pyFiles` being the additional internal libraries that are being used.  My advice would be to provision the server with a bootstrap action which copies your own libraries over, and installs the pip-installable libraries on the master and nodes.